# What do I use the Classic strangifier with?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I just unlocked a Mann Co. Supply crate key and got a "Classic strangifier", which apparently changes normal items to strange items. However, when I click "Use with...", it says that I have no eligible items to use with the strangifier. I've been playing for a while and have plenty of weapons. How can I use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strangifier is used on a weapon called "The Classic". It's a primary weapon for the sniper. When used on the weapon it turns it into a strange Classic which starts counting kills for it. You probably just don't have a classic in your inventory to use it on.

Comment: Cheers. Well that was a waste of £1.49 -_-

Comment: @imulsion According to [backpack.tf](http://backpack.tf/pricelist/spreadsheet), a strange Classic is worth around 6 refined (currently 0.77 keys or £1.15). It's worth less than you paid, but it's not worthless. You can easily acquire a Classic through trading, use your strangifier, and then trade the strange Classic for something else you want.